# A mathematical expression parser with custom data structures

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, parsing, calculator

I recently wrote a mathematical expression parser in C++. The software can read valid mathematical expressions and evaluate them. An example of an expression the code can parse is `(sin(pi)*e^(-3))`. I would love to receive constructive feedback if possible for the code. Such as compiler optimizations, memory optimization and algorithms improvements.

The important methods are:

1. `tokenize`
2. `pre_process_trig_and_constants`
3. `evaluate`
4. `eval_with_braces`

The important structs are:

1. `toks_and_ops`
2. `expr_stack`

`tokenize`

```
toks_and_ops parser::tokenize(string expr){
    /**
     * This method tokenizes a string (without braces) into numbers and operands. The string must be a valid mathematical expression
     * It is recommended to be called from evaluate() method since there is no support for braces.
     * For evaluation of expressions with braces check out struct expr_stack.
     *
     */
    const int len= expr.size();
    string tok ="";
    char current_char;

    // struct toks_and_ops is used here and the following vector<> members are for the struct feilds.
    vector<double> toks;
    vector<char> ops ;
    int current_index=0;

    while(current_index<len){

        current_char=expr.at(current_index);
        /**
         * check if the character is  a number a.k.a between values 57 and 48 in ASCII
         *'.' is 46 in ASCII and - is 45
         *This method is faster than cross referencing character with every other numbers
         */
        if((current_char<58 && current_char>44) && current_char != 47){

            if(current_char == MINUS){

                if(expr.at(current_index -1) > 47 &&  expr.at(current_index -1) <58){
                    /**
                     * Pure subtraction is considered as addition of a negative value.
                     * if the character before the minus sign is a number its a pure subtraction
                     * if the character before is an operation it is a normal operation
                     * It is guaranteed that there will be always one character before minus sign
                     * evaluate() method will append '0' before an expression if the first character is '-'
                     * Furthermore evaluate() will only work with expressions without braces so an error is not possible
                     */
                    ops.push_back(PLUS);
                    toks.push_back(get_num(tok));
                    tok="";
                }
            }
            tok +=current_char;

        }else{
            /**
             * If the character is not a number , '.' or '-'
             */
            toks.push_back( get_num(tok));
            ops.push_back(current_char);
            tok="";

        }
        current_index++;
    }
    toks.push_back(get_num(tok));
    toks_and_ops res ={toks,ops};
    return res;

}
```

`pre_process_trig_and_constants`

```
string parser::pre_process_trig_and_constants(string source){


    source =replace_expr(source,"sin","s");
    source =replace_expr(source,"cos", "c");
    source =replace_expr(source,"tan", "t");
    source =replace_expr(source,"e", to_string(exp(1)));
    source =replace_expr(source,"pi", to_string(M_PI));
    return source;



}
```

`evaluate`
**WARNING**: This is long.

```
double parser::evaluate(string expr){

    /**
     * Central method for evaluation.
     * This method is not directly called by the user
     * This method serves as a helper for the structure expr_stack to evaluate expressions with braces
     * This method can be called if required to evaluate simple expressions i.ewithout any braces.
     */
    if(expr.empty()){

        return 1;
    }if(expr.at(0) == MINUS){
        /**
         *  preventing an error for tokenize() method
         */
        expr ="0" +expr;
    }if(expr.size() ==1 ){

        return get_num(expr);
    }

    toks_and_ops r =tokenize(expr);
    int ops_index=0;
    /**
     * The operations use BEDMAS
     * In this context we exclude braces since this method does not evaluate expression with brace
     * Power takes precedence then * ->/ -> +
     * Indirectly expressions inside brackets are evaluated first by the expression_stack
     */
    for(auto i = r.ops.begin(); i< r.ops.end();){

        if(*i == POWER){

            r.toks[ops_index] = pow(r.toks[ops_index] , r.toks[ops_index+1]);
            remov(ops_index+1, r.toks);
            remov(ops_index, r.ops);


        }else{

            i++;
            ops_index++;
        }
    }
    if(r.toks.size() ==1){

        return r.toks[0];
    }
    ops_index=0;

    for(auto i = r.ops.begin(); i< r.ops.end();){

        if(*i == MULTI){

            r.toks[ops_index] =r.toks[ops_index+1] * r.toks[ops_index];
            remov(ops_index+1, r.toks);
            remov(ops_index, r.ops);


        }else{

            i++;
            ops_index++;
        }
    }

    if(r.toks.size() ==1){

        return r.toks[0];

    }
    ops_index=0;

    for(auto i = r.ops.begin(); i< r.ops.end();){

        if(*i == DIV){

            r.toks[ops_index] = r.toks[ops_index] / r.toks[ops_index+1];
            remov(ops_index+1, r.toks);
            remov(ops_index, r.ops);
        }else{

            i++;
            ops_index++;
        }
    }

    if(r.toks.size() ==1){

        return r.toks[0];
    }
    ops_index=0;

    for(auto i = r.ops.begin(); i< r.ops.end();){

        if(*i == PLUS){

            r.toks[ops_index] = r.toks[ops_index+1] + r.toks[ops_index];
            remov(ops_index+1, r.toks);
            remov(ops_index, r.ops);
        }else{

            i++;
            ops_index++;
        }
    }
    return r.toks[0];

};
```

`eval_with_braces`

```
double parser::eval_with_braces(string expr){

    /**
     * evaluates expressions with braces
     * see expr_stack structure for more information on evaluation of expressions with braces
     */
    expr_stack eval;
    expr_stack trig_eval;
    int ind=0;
    int trig_ind;
    string temp="";
    string sec_temp="";

    expr.erase( remove(expr.begin(),expr.end(), ' '), expr.end());
    expr = pre_process_trig_and_constants(expr);
    expr =expr+"+0";
    for(auto i =expr.begin();i<expr.end();){

        if((*i!=SIN && *i !=COS) && *i != TAN){

            eval.push(*i);
            i++;
            ind++;
        }else{


            trig_ind =ind+1;

            //isolates the immediate valid expression after trig indicator i.e sin, cos or tan
            while(!trig_eval.expr_done){

                trig_eval.push(expr.at(trig_ind));
                trig_ind++;
            }



            if(*i== SIN){

                temp= to_string(round_val(sin(evaluate(trig_eval.expr))));
            }else if(*i== COS){

                temp= to_string(round_val(cos(evaluate(trig_eval.expr))));
            }else{
                temp= to_string(round_val(tan(evaluate(trig_eval.expr))));
            }

            sec_temp =expr.substr(0,ind) ;
            sec_temp+= temp;
            sec_temp+=expr.substr(ind+ trig_eval.push_count +1);
            expr=sec_temp;

            sec_temp="";
            temp="";
            trig_eval.recycle();
            trig_ind=0;

        }
    }
    return evaluate(eval.expr);
};
```

`toks_and_ops`

```
   struct toks_and_ops{
    
        /**
         * compound data type for conveninece
         */
        vector<double> toks;
        vector<char> ops;
    
    };
```

`expr_stack`

```
struct expr_stack{

    /**
     * member fields
     * */
    bool expr_done =false;
    int ind=0;
    int prev= -1;
    int push_count=0;
    vector<int> prev_l_bracs;
    string expr="";
    string ref;

    /**
     * for re-initializing this stack
     */
    void recycle(){
        /**
         * sets all members fields to initial value
         */
        expr_done =false;
        ind=0;
        prev= -1;
        push_count=0;
        prev_l_bracs.clear();
        expr="";
        ref="";

    }
    /**
     * method for the stack
     * */
    void push(char i){
        /**
         * The algorithm for push() dynamically checks for complete braces ( complete braces are a pair of adjacent ( and ) )
         * If more left braces are found the current starting index of a brace to be completed is updated as the index of most recent left brace
         * While there is a left brace and a right brace is found , it denotes a valid brace expression and the contents inside it is evaluated as
         * a mathematical expression by calling evaluate()
         *  After this the current starting index for a brace to be completed is updates as the most recent one before the previousleft brace
         *  The previous valid brace expression is replaced by the result of the evaluation
         *
         *  Once a full valid brace expression is completely pushed inside this stack there will not be any braces left and
         *  evaluate() method can be called to evaluate it.
         *
         *  expr_stack acts like a pre-processor for expressions
         */
        push_count++;

        if(i == LBRAC){

            prev_l_bracs.push_back(ind);
            prev= ind;
            expr+= i;
            ind++;
        }else if(i == RBRAC && prev>=0){


            ref=expr.substr(prev +1 , ind -prev  );
            ref=to_string(evaluate(ref));

            expr = expr.substr(0, prev)+ ref;
            ind =prev+ ref.size();
            remov(prev_l_bracs.size() -1 ,prev_l_bracs);

            if(!prev_l_bracs.empty()){

                prev = (prev_l_bracs.at(prev_l_bracs.size()-1));
            }else{

                prev =-1;
                expr_done = true;
            }

        }else{

            expr+= i;
            ind++;
        }
    };
};
```

Please ask or comment if any clarification is needed, or if anything is ambiguous :)

Answer (score 2):

### Constant parameters

```
parser::tokenize(string expr){
```

would be better off as

```
parser::tokenize(const string &expr) {
```

Similarly for `pre_process_trig_and_constants`, which should use an intermediate variable for the reassignment statements in that function.

### Encapsulation

```
toks_and_ops res ={toks,ops};
```

Rather than structures that don't know how to initialize themselves - such as this `toks_and_ops` - I would sooner see a constructor for this `toks_and_ops` as class that accepts a `const string &expr` and does most of what `tokenize` is doing now.

### ASCII symbols

```
if((current_char<58 && current_char>44) && current_char != 47){
```

is very difficult to understand and maintain. Given that you say you're already assuming ASCII, as long as your compiler is [configured to also apply ASCII to literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794590/how-does-file-encoding-affect-c11-string-literals), you should just be using character literals like `'.'` .

### For-loop

```
int current_index=0;

while(current_index<len){
    // ...

    current_index++;
}
```

should just be

```
for (int current_index = 0; current_index < len; current_index++) {
```